# "oembed is null" error in firebug console (JQUERY OEMBED)

Tags: javascript, jquery, console, firebug, oembed

Im having a problem with oembed outputting an error in firebug's console windows as such:

```
oembed is null
oembedContainer.html(oembed.code);
```

which is when clicked will point to the jquery.oembed.js file.
my declaration of oembed is that it will replace all links with a class name of oembed, like so:

```
$(".oembed").oembed(null, {
                        embedMethod: "replace", 
                        maxWidth: 350,
                        maxHeight: 350,
                        vimeo: { autoplay: false, maxWidth: 350, maxHeight: 350 }                 
                        });
```

i think the error is pointing on the first parameter of the function oembed().
but i really dont know what is happening inside, do somebody know a workaround here?? 
This is the link where I got the code:
http://code.google.com/p/jquery-oembed/

Comment: I have a different version at https://github.com/starfishmod/jquery-oembed-all which may be helpful?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem until I noticed the snippet had a non absolute url for loading the script. Therefore it never loaded at all. Change this:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="../../jquery.oembed.js"></script>`

For the actual url of your script, for example, if you're testing it local and both the html test page and the script are in the same folder:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.oembed.min.js"></script>`

That will do the trick.